# Jquery Hover box background position works on Browser, breaks on Ipad, anyway to fix this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made a website that has a quote tab off to the right hand side of the website. When you hover over the tab the position changes and people can select different dates to receive a quote for. This works well across every browser. Recently I opened it on and Ipad and the box still appears with the correct data in it but it's in full view the whole time, not just the tab. There's no hover state on it anymore. What I would like to do is on the Ipad have it so that I can drag the tab over or tap it and have the tab slide to the full width of the box just like the browser. Here is my mark-up

HTML:

```
<div id="quote">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#quote').css({
            backgroundPosition: "0 0"
        }).hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                height: '150px',
                width: '250px',
                backgroundPosition: "(200px 0px)"
            }, {
                duration: 900
            });
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                height: '150px',
                width: '150px',
                backgroundPosition: "(0px 200px)"
            }, {
                duration: 900
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

css:

```
#quote {
    position: absolute;    
    top: 100px;
    right: -85px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background:red;
    transition:right 2s;
    -webkit-transition:right 2s /* Safari */
    -moz-transition:right 2s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-color:#9C1818;
    color: white;
}

#quote:hover {
    right: -15px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
     -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
}

#quote p {
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#quote:hover p {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#quote {
background: #9C1818;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-right: -100px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 60px!important;

}

#quote p {
    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */
margin-top: 59px;
margin-left: -50px;
color: white;
}

#quote:hover p {
     transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari */
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
     -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Firefox */
     -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
     -o-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
     color: white;
     margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Here's how it works on the browser:
http://jsfiddle.net/mandykiwi/Jfz4F/

I'm sure there is a tonne of extra css in there but it works so I'm not touching it unless I have to.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? it only seems to be on Apple devices that this happens. 
Thanks

Comment: There is no way to hover on a mobile device since there is no mouse. you'll have to make an if statement to change it into a click feature when on a certain screen size.

Comment: i agree with @JoshPowell you can use if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // Do something
} else {
 // Do something else
}